# Can't log in to my database. Error: "Param is missing or the value is empty: user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a trouble with my logging in. It highlights the user_params function as an error in users controller. What could it be?
[image]

**/views/sessions/new.html.erb or login form**

```
<h1>Log In</h1>

<%= form_tag users_path do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= text_field :email, params[:email] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Log In" %></div>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged In!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to signup_path, notice: "Logged out!"
  end

end
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to user_tasks, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private


  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

**controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


 private


    def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    helper_method :current_user

    def authorize
      redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" if current_user.nil?
    end
end
```

**rake routes**
[image]

Generated parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jtdA0rITCiFjU9ECiKnDUMh/MHMpqv6u+Bd65PAfpARwYsmb9Dli32wpULfmYa7wpBQiFYxAGHF6flCfJgPOew==", "email"=>"dsadsa", "password"=>[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log In"}
```

Any help?

Comment: why don't you initialize `User` object and use `form_for` ?

Comment: @Nithin For that purpose I would need a Session model, because form_for doesn't work without a model. But creating a Session model is unlogical.

Comment: Are you dealing with session objects or user objects in the form?

Comment: @Nithin When an user logs in It's supposed to create a session. When the user logs out the sessions should destroy.

Comment: Can you post the params log generated?

Comment: @Pavan I'm sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: I mean the server log which generates the params while submitting the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line and try please.

```
<%= text_field :email, params[:email] %>
```

to

```
<%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
```

Also majorly add this in your routes file to redirect it to sessions controller create action.

```
post '/authenticate' => 'sessions#create'
```

change this tag

```
<%= form_tag users_path do %>
```

to

```
<%= form_tag /authenticate do %>
```

Comment: Still having the same problem.

Comment: please tell me if you want to redirect it to users controller create action or sessions controller because currently it is going to users controller. if you want to go to users controller you need form_for not form_tag with @user object. secondly. i cant see sessions#create in your routes so you cannot redirect to session controller

Comment: It should create a session while user logs in and then redirect him to 'users' or 'tasks'. It doesn't matter where to go. The fact is that doesn't log in. Session#create action exists in my session controller and I'm not able to use form_for because I have no Session model.

Comment: i dont think this is happening right now. users_path in form_tag is redirecting it to the users controller. first of all try to write raise in sessions@create and see if it gives run time error. if it does it means that it is atlease going to session controller. if it is not remove from sessions and add it to users#create and confirm if it is going there. if it is going to users#create. then your form_tag is not going to help. as you are permitting params that requires user

Comment: You were right. It redirects to the user controller. And is there any way to fix the problem?

Comment: Honestly I've no clue what to do now.

Comment: try this: change <%= form_tag users_path do %> to <%= form_tag /login do %>
and move your code of sessions#create action to sessions#new action please

Comment: let me know if it makes sense. else i will put the code in answer.

Comment: Now It says "No route matches [POST] "/login" " when submitting the form

Comment: can you add this to routes file:    post  '/authenticate'                 => 'sessions#create' and change this <%= form_tag users_path do %> to <%= form_tag /authenticate do %> this should work..

Comment: Rewrite the main answer :)

Comment: sure thing. let me write this.

Answer (score 1):

When you look into the `params`, they are not coming from the `user`. Try changing your `user_params` like below

```
def user_params
   params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem. Could I ask something else? For example I have a route: users/user_id/tasks/:id/tasks(.:format). How can I correctly interpreter this route in some form_for url: ?

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko For that your `form_for` will look like `<%= form_for [@user, @task] do |f| %>`. And please accept my answer :)

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. This answer solved the error but not the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you keep the `:user` namespace for params in your form

```
<%= form_tag users_path do |form| %>

    <%= fields_for :user do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :email, params[:email] %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Log In" %></div>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

So you can still use `params.require(:user)` in your controller as usual

Parameters will look like this

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"jtdA0rITCiFjU9ECiKnDUMh/MHMpqv6u+Bd65PAfpARwYsmb9Dli32wpULfmYa7wpBQiFYxAGHF6flCfJgPOew==", 
  "user" => {
    "email"=>"dsadsa", 
    "password"=>[FILTERED], 
  },
  "commit"=>"Log In"
}
```